# Web application to a multiplatform phone app

Tags: web-development, mobile, asp-classic

I'm really lost here so I hope some can help me.

I have to develop a phone application on every platform so i tough of using phonegap. Seems pretty nice.

I have a web application coded in classic Asp and it's this webApplication that i need to strip down to be a phone app.

At first at thought it will be simple, my classic Asp render some html so phonegap is able to put it as an app.

But it's not that simple, because in my asp I have some code that is rendered server side, I've talked to some who tell me that some html could call the asp pages and this html could be used in phonegap. Don't think it's possible ...

Well if someone could help me here, maybe i've said wrong thing in my little text dont hesitate to correct me :)

My solution (i think) : code some webServices in asp.net that will use the same database as my asp classic web application. And some html and jquery will call the webservices and those html and jquery will go trough phoneGap

Well thanks for the help and saying what you think about it ! :)

**Simple question : What is the best way to transfer an asp classic web app to a multiplatform phone app ?**

Answer (score 2):

It's really two different problems, and you can't really "port" the application as-is. Your ASP application is running in a server environment, whereas phonegap runs locally stored HTML/Javascript/CSS within the phone's environment.

Going the route of writing some webservices that will be consumed by jQuery is going to be your best bet if you are trying to write a "native" application that can be downloaded from an App Marketplace.

If you just want to display your website on a mobile phone, find a device detection library, and use that to either redirect or change your layout (and CSS) so that it's formatted for a smaller screen

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way: re-think it and re-write it. Developing for phones is different from developing for desktops.

Comment: and working with classic asp sucks

Comment: @Ryathal: I can only agree :)